# Why is my custom function adding an additional "/!" (Vim)?

Tags: vim

I want to turn this:

```
A
a
a
B
b
b
```

into this:

```
a/!
a/!
b/!
b/!
```

So I wrote a custom function:

```
function PrepareDic()
  :g/[A-Z]/d | :%s/$/\/!/g
endfunction
```

But when I do `:PrepareDic()` I end up with something like this instead:

```
a/!/!
a/!/!
b/!/!
b/!/!
```

What I'm I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you wrote a function you don't need to chain commands like that. (Chaining command like that also doesn't do what you expect.)

The global command can not be separated by bar. Instead what it is doing is running `d | :%s/$/\/!/g` on every line with `[A-Z]`. This is obviously wrong. To fix this you just need to run the substitute command after the global command (which is what you intended). Since there are two lines with capital letters the substitution is done twice. So you get `/!/!` add the end of every line.

So the following should be the fixed function.

```
function PrepareDic()
  g/[A-Z]/d
  %s/$/\/!/g
endfunction
```

---

If you really want to use bar to separate commands you need to pass the global to `exec`. However this isn't really necessary.

```
exec 'g/[A-Z]/d' | %s/$/\/!/g
```